# My UDP checksum calculation gives wrong results every time

Tags: udp, checksum, packet

I am trying to manually calculate checksums for various UDP packets, but I am always getting the wrong results compared to what is shown in Wireshark. Below is an example of how I do it:

```
Source Address: 192.168.0.103 (0xC0A8, 0x0067)
Destination Address: 192.168.0.1 (0xC0A8, 0x0001)

Source Port: 57090 (0xDF02)
Destination Port: 8000 (0x1F40)

Packet length: 19 (0x0013)
Data: hello world (0x6865, 0x6C6C, 0x6F20, 0x776F, 0x726C, 0x6400)

Expected checksum: 0xEDFD (from wireshark)
```

I understand that the UDP checksum is calculated with the following variables:

```
Source IP + Destination IP + 17 (0x0011 - protocol code) + 10 (0x000A - pseudoheader length) + Source Port + Destination Port + UDP Packet Length + Data
```

All of them in groups of 16 bits.

So my calculations are (in the same order):

```
0xC0A8 + 0x0067 + 0xC0A8 + 0x0001 + 0x0011 + 0x000A + 0xDF02 + 0x1F40 + 0x0013 + 0x6865 + 0x6C6C + 0x6F20 + 0x776F + 0x726C + 0x6400
```

The result of the above sum is:

```
0x511F4
```

Now, since the result is higher than 0xFFFF I do the following:

```
0x11F4 + 0x0005 = 0x11F9
```

After flipping the bits I get the result:

```
0xEE06 <- which, as you can see, it is different from the expected one
```

So my question is what am I doing wrong? I am always getting *almost* the result of what is shown in wireshark.

Below is a screenshot of the packet inside Wireshark, as a reference
https://www.evernote.com/l/AWl0H1AGoxpGX4_zjgDlVBcytJM-HP_PvQE

Comment: There is an RFC on this. Have you read it?

Comment: Yes, I read RFC768.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found what I was doing wrong, in case somebody else has a similar issue.

The way I was computing the pseudo header was like this:

```
Source IP + Destination IP + 17 (0x0011 - protocol code) + 10 (0x000A - pseudoheader length)
```

The problem was at the length byte. It should be the UDP packet length, not the pseudoheader length.

The final formula is this:

```
Source IP + Destination IP + 17 (0x0011 - protocol code) + UDP Packet Length + Source Port + Destination Port + UDP Packet Length + Data
```

Notice the UDP Packet length appears twice. First for the pseudoheader and second for the actual UDP header.